# Magento2 : How To Solve Controller 404 Not Found Error On Live Server

Tags: magento2, controllers, server-setup, 404

I have create one controller and it is working fine in **local environment**
but when i upload that files to **live server** is shows 404 not found error,

These are my code, please let me know if anyone have idea about this issue.

**controller URL:** http://127.0.0.1/test/product/index

> app/code/Vendor/Test/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
  <router id="standard">
    <route id="test" frontName="test">
      <module name="Vendor_Test"/>
    </route>
  </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Test/Controller/Product/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Test\Controller\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hello1";
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: localhost/magento2/test/product/index                                 
               **//magento2 replace with project name**

Comment: thanks for answer but there was an issue of compilation,becuase controller classs was not generated in generated folder

Comment: static content deploy

Comment: using this : php bin/magento setup:di:compile issue solved

Comment: remove your var/cache folder then execute this command in your command promt php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove your var/cache folder then execute this command in your command promt

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Hope This Will Help You !!!**